# I need to generate Markov chain in R, there is given transaction matrix and pseudo random numbers sequence. How to implement that sequence?

Tags: r, markov-chains

My pseudo random numbers sequence and transaction matrix:

```
a1=293
c1=123
m1=584
x1<-c()
x1[1] = 5

#generating pseudo random numbers sequence
for (i in 1:(m1-1)){
  x1[i+1]=(a1*x1[i]+c1)%%m1}

#matrix
statesNames<-c('1', '2', '3', '4')
tm <- matrix(c(0.5,0.5,0,0,1/3,1/3,1/3,0,0,1/3,1/3,1/3,0,0,0.5,0.5), nrow=4, byrow=TRUE)

mat<-new("markovchain", states = statesNames, transitionMatrix = tm)
```

Now I need to use that pseudo random numbers sequence to generate Markov chain, but how to do that ?

Comment: To properly do this you need a vector with starting probabilities.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.